# Finding out if it is possible to balance out debts between people using a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

Say a bunch of friends went on a trip. Something went wrong, and when they got back, some were not friends anymore. Now we need to find a way to split the cost of the trip. Some people are owed money (because they paid too much) and some are owing (paid too little).

Say we have two lists, debts and relationship. The debts list contains a list of integers. Each integer is a person. A positive integer means they owe that much money, negative means that are owed that much. Relationships is a list of tuples that shows if two people are friends. For instance (0, 3) would mean that debts[0] and debts[3] are friends. I'm trying to find a way to see if everyone can get even by transferring money between people.

An example:

```
debts = [5, -5, 10]
relationship = [(0, 1), (1, 2)]
```

The way I was thinking was making a graph to construct the relationships between each individual. Using DFS, I would start with the first person, clear their debt (i.e make it 0) and passing that money on to the next person. Eventually I would have gone through everyone and if at the end the last person does not have a value of 0, it is not possible to get even.

Am I on the correct path? I believe this would take O(|V|+|E|)

Comment: There's an algorithm that does one DFS, but it clears on leaving a node, not entering.

Comment: Why relationship is needed? Or only friends can pass money?